# In IT, how should it be, "View Option List" or "See Option List"?

Tags: word-choice

In the IT field, the interface of a computer program displays a button that shows the user a list of options when clicked. What should be the verb used in the button's text? "View Option List" or "See Option List"?

Please, note that what I'm asking for is the difference of usage between these two particular words. I know I could use some other verb like "show" or "display", or just say "Option List" and whatnot. What I want to know is about word choice in this particular field for these two particular words: "view" and "see", which to me, seem to have the same meaning when referring to displaying an option list on a web page. I need to know what sounds more natural to a native, which one would be more expected to be seen, and what difference there is to prefer one over the other. Simple word choice.

Comment: This is more a UX question than English, but it would usually either just say 'options' or it wouldn't say anything at all & have something like  gear menu ⚙︎, or burger, kebab or any of the myriad other menu types named after food.

Comment: Unnecessary verbiage is to be avoided in UIs. There's absolutely no need to include a verb at all, so don't bother. Perhaps at work your manager has his own office, with a sign saying "Manager" on the door. You wouldn't expect ***Meet** Manager **here***, or ***Come in to see the** Manager* on that physical doorway, for the same reason you don't need a verb on the virtual onscreen doorway that leads to another part of your app's user interface.

Comment: @DoneWithThis.: I think using images rather than text is primarily motivated by a desire for language-independent UI's on the part of the developers. It's my understanding that ***OK*** is the best-known word in the world, so maybe there's not much pressure to make the relevant button show a tick image instead of a text label. But for more exotic options, it can be a bit of a pain figuring out what the various icons mean (especially if the images are too small and/or feature  highly stylized representations). Image-based UIs often suit the developers more than the users, imho.

Comment: ...Also consider newspapers, which often feature shorts "trailers" on the front page for items which are covered more extensively on *inside* pages. Such "trailers" normally just end with something like ***Full Story - Page 10*** (not ***Read the** full story on Page 10*). But in a UI you don't even need to bother with the "address" component ("Page 10") of the "signpost" button, because the mere act of clicking on it immediately takes you there anyway.

Comment: What difference does the dictionary give, and what don't you like about that? In other words: please show some basic research and be more specific about your problem.

Comment: I think I've been quite specific about what I'm looking for. But I'll edit the question. I need to know what sounds more natural to a native, which one would be more expected to be seen, and what difference there is to prefer one over the other. Simple word choice.  I'm not asking about UX nor alternatives to this text, as I've explained in the question. Of course, I've read the dictionary and I've looked around the internet to see what they use, and I've seen both options being used, so I come here asking for nuances, things a native notice and confirmation.

Comment: (1) Look at other applications to see what they do (2) Be consistent among all your menus and other messages rather than mixing see and view. It's a matter of opinion, and you'll have to do your own work.

Comment: See https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/117058/microcopy-is-the-cta-verb-see-in-line-with-ada . In my experience most applications use "view" over "see" (both traditionally and due to reasons outlined in the answer), but I concur with the rest of the commenters that just "Options" is usually preferred for buttons. (It'd be a different story for eg. a checkbox that drives whether an option list is displayed or not).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's why people employ UX / UI designers for their apps and websites, along with user testing. If you want to get it right and understood by all your potential users, let the experts do it.

Comment: @PeterJennings: Yeah, but my goals and those of "the experts" aren't necessarily aligned. They're usually interested in finding the "lowest common denominator", in order to maximize the "reach" of the UI. Sometimes that means I have to wrestle with a less-than-intuitive UI because it works (perhaps only "barely adequately") for a wider range of cultures, ages, etc.

Answer (score 2):

"View options" sounds better. This is simply because it is what is used most of the time. In another universe, it could have been "see options." I would drop the "list," personally, but this doesn't change the answer between "view" and "see."